# natbib author-year citation - fallback to editor possible when author missing?

Tags: latex, bibliography

I'm having an issue with the natbib package. When the bib entry is missing an author I want to display the editor instead. However the second citation just takes the first three letters of the bib-key instead of the author.

Sample tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\begin{document}

I need this \citet[S.~2]{Test1} to look like Surname (2022, S. 2).
and this \citep{Test1} like (Surname, 2022)

But also this \citet[S.~2]{Test2} to look like Editor (2022, S. 2).
and this \citep{Test2} like (Editor, 2022)
but it just prints (Tes, 2022)

\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

The bib file could look like this:

```
@misc{Test1,
    author={Surname, Name}
    title = {Sometitle},
    year = {2022}
}
@misc{Test2,
    title = {Someothertitle},
    editor={{Editor, Name}}
    year = {2022}
}
```

Can anyone help with this? I'd also switch to another package than natbib, since I'm still early on the project. But at a first glance it seemed to meet my needs quite well.
Also I don't really know what I'm doing, it's been a while since I've been working with Latex. So sorry for that in advance!

Comment: Rule of thumb: if your bibtex bibstyle does not happen to give exactly the output you want, switch to biblatex instead. This is much easier to customise.

Comment: Thanks. I switched to biblatex with the natbib option - `\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}`. Was way easier than I expected.

Comment: Welcome to the biblatex world :)

Answer (score -2):

Although the user posting the initial question here was able to switch to `biblatex` (which is good), not everyone has that freedom for some publishing venues.  If this applies to you (that you have to stay with `natbib` and `plainnat`, you may be interested in [a TeX Stack Exchange post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54441/bib-sorting-without-author/657104#657104) that provides a description of how you can customize your BST file to modify your sorting, including configuring `misc` to sort by `author` then `editor`.

**EDIT:**  A down-check for this answer being unhelpful inspired me to be more specific than my original answer above so the additional details specific to this case are below.

Since your provided code has `natbib` using `abbrvnat` (not `plainnat` as in the linked example that I initially provided), you can find `abbrvnat.bst` in your TeX repository and place a local copy with a different name (like `abbrvnat-copy.bst`) into your working directory.  There are two steps in modifying your local copy of `abbrvnat-copy.bst`:  First, update the `calc.short.authors` function to also look for an `editor` in the `misc` type.  Second, have your TeX file use your newly customized BST file.

Note:  I am using the 2007 version of `abbrvnat.bst`, which is the latest as of this posting in 2022.

1. In your local copy of `abbrvnat-copy.bst`, search for the `calc.short.authors` function.  We'll need to add two lines of code to it:

```
  type$ "misc" =
  or
```

I show the new version here:

```
FUNCTION {calc.short.authors}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
  type$ "misc" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.label
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.organization.label
        { type$ "manual" =
            'author.key.organization.label
            'author.key.label
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
  'short.list :=
}
```

2. In your TeX file, you'll need to change this line to account for your newly customized file:  `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat-copy}`.  Other than this one line in your main .tex file and adding a couple missing commas in your .bib file, I did not change any code in your MWE.

Here's the output:
[image: compiled and typeset output with customized BST file]

Other aspects that you may want to address (that you didn't ask about) include getting the editor(s) to appear in the bibliography (references list) for `misc` entries and sorting by `editor` for `misc` entries.  The example that I provided here and the example provided in the other post that I previously linked should both be helpful in customizing your BST file to achieve your desired bibliography style.